# Why Every Router has the same default ip address?

Tags: networking, router

```
C:\Users\minatoots1>ping 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 4ms, Average = 2ms
```

Why Every Router has the same default ip address?

Comment: They don't. Depends on brand and maker really.

Comment: Making it an actual question really helps. Your example simply shows that you're running a ping on an IP but that doesn't mean it even has to be a router. Certai addresses might be more common because you need an initial connection to a router in order to configure them.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. They do not have the same address. Many use 192.168.1.1 because it's the 1st address usable that way from the 192.168.* private class.

Answer (score 0):

There is a range of IP addresses that are reserved for private networks (192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255). The default IP address of a router is usually the first address within that range, which is 192.168.1.1.

However, note that there are also reserved IP addresses from 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255 and 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255, so contrary to your question, not every router has the same IP address

Answer to a similar question can be found in the Network Engineering SE: [Why 192.168.1.1 is most common default gateway for routers? [closed]](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18843/why-192-168-1-1-is-most-common-default-gateway-for-routers)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Will do @gronostaj

Comment: The first host address in the RFC1918 `192.168.0.0/24` space is `192.168.0.1`, not `192.168.1.1`.  Further, beyond SOHO grade equipment, many routers have non-RFC1918 addresses on their interfaces, so noting the other RFC1918 ranges really has nothing to do with the (correct) assertion "not every router has the same IP address."